# formatting returned values from callback functions

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, callback

I'm creating a simple library using google map v3. The concept is to divide every features of google maps into modular functions, for example, calling geolocation will return just the coordinate, so that this coordinate can be used for displaying map, or decoded into address strings, or as marker location. Google Maps is asynchronous and to achieve these 'modularity', every functions must have callback that returns the value into callback block.

I'm using a simple example below :

```
//simple functions
function set(callback) {
    var test = 'a String';
    callback(test);    
}
function print(val) {
    alert(val);   
}

//run

set(function(){
    print(arguments[0]); 
    //will be followed by another function, dll
});
```

As you can see, inside the callback block, I can retrieve the returned value by accessing `arguments` variable. Well yes, even though it works, it doesn't look informative. What I want to achieve is **how can I rename `arguments` into something informative** such as `lon`, `lat`, etc. So I don't have to access arguments[0] for x, arguments[1] for y, which are different from function to function.

My expectation is, using the above example, is it possible to call `print(test)` rather than `print(arguments[0])` ? I expect to use the exact variable values and name I dumped inside `callback(//here//)` without creating any global variable before it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the name you gave the local variable inside `set`, but you can name it in the function you're passing *into* `set`:

```
set(function(test){
    print(test); 
    //will be followed by another function, dll
});
```

...which is arguably more useful, because you're naming it where you're going to use it.

Comment: I see, so I can wrap multiple variable as object, for example inside set test = { lat:12345,lon:12345 };callback(test) then using your solution set(function(test) { print(test.lat) }); etc. Thanks. :) but before I pick an answer I will wait for other people's alternatives first (later if any)